# How to set from command line "select interpreter" of "ms-python.python"?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have installed this extension.
[image]

Is there any way I can set the select interpreter path from command line?

Comment: May I ask why you need to set the select interpreter path from command line? Only to use commandline script?

Comment: @rustyhuYes only to use command line script. Because you have to restart and install an environment 6-7 times a day, life becomes living hell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it through the file `settings.json` either in vscode user domain or in a vscode workspace `.vscode` path.

```json
{
    //...
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "python" // the default path
}
```

If you want you could modify `settings.json` through commandline.

Comment: For me `settings.json` is not available anywhere, Idk why

Comment: @user27286 You can create `settings.json` for your workspace or user (in Windows usually in path like `C:\Users\{YOUR_USERNAME}\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`.